# File empty after LoadFromDataTable EPPlus .net

Tags: c#, .net, epplus

Good morning, sir, 
I've been using EPPlus for some time, and I have a problem, I want to create an excel spreadsheet and I use the "LoadFromDataTable" function, my file is well created, its weight is the expected one but when I open this file it is empty.
Could you tell me why?

```
    FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(templateExcel);
    ExcelPackage excelPackage = new ExcelPackage(fileInfo, false);

    ExcelWorksheet worksheet = excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Actions");

    worksheet.Cells["C6"].LoadFromDataTable(dtFinal, false);
    worksheet.Cells[1, 8].Value = DateTime.Now;
    worksheet.Cells[3, 3].Value = "Liste des AEs Ouvrage " + row["IDEIdentifiant"].ToString();
    worksheet.Hidden = eWorkSheetHidden.Visible;

    excelPackage.SaveAs(new FileInfo(fichierSortie));
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. What have you tried so far? Please provide a mimimun compilable verifyable example.

Comment: Are you really using C with .net or is it C#?

Comment: I use C# sorry, .net

Comment: the code looks good. did you check `Actions` sheet? and is `dtFinal` having enough records?

Comment: I have checked my "actions" sheet and my datatable is well informed.